# What does CPU frequency represent in an Arduino board?

Tags: arduino, cpu, microcontroller, frequency

I'm new to Arduino and microcontrollers.

I was studying the specs and found that even the same board may have different frequencies with different input voltages (3.3V vs 5V). So the question is, what does frequency represent? Does it represent how many lines of assembly code it's able to run? Or the maximum PWM frequencies it's able to output?

A further question would be, if I'm looking for a board for a specific project, how do I decide which frequency I will need a priori, instead of trying everything out and see which one works?

What makes me more confused is that when it comes to computer CPUs, it seems that lower frequency CPUs can actually run faster than higher frequency ones (e.g. Intel). So how do I actually know how fast a microcontroller can run?

Comment: What do you mean by "it seems that lower frequency CPUs can actually run faster than higher frequency ones (e.g. Intel)"?

Comment: Why do you think that AVR is faster than common CPUs?

Comment: on your last one: computer CPUs have a lot of extra parts that are used to accelerate common computing tasks like mpeg decoding, crypto, calculating networking checksums, etc. Because they can do such sub-tasks without many "main cpu" cycles, some slower-clocked CPUs can run code faster than un-accelerated yet higher-clocked chips. In the same notion, hardware SPI or serial will use a lot less cpu than bit-banged versions of the same, which require delecate timing and throttling of the CPU; in those soft cases, having more clock speed lets the "emulation" be more precise and consistent.

Answer (score 6):

By frequency we mean the frequency of the CPU clock. Say your Arduino Uno runs on 16 MHz, which is 16,000,000 Hertz. 
That means there are 16 Million clock cycles per second. The CPU executes the byte-code of the program. One Assembler instruction can actually take any number of CPU cycles to execute, usually between 1 and 4 cycles for simple stuff, and a little bit more heavy arithmetic and writing to memory. So it's a rough estimate of how many "lines of assembler" (that is, byte-code instructions) it can run per second. A measurement which is a little bit better is the "MIPS" value, the "Millions of instructions per second". There are other benchmark types for CPUs which are more accurate.

If you take at the datasheet for the AVR microprocessor architecture, you can see the cycles that each instructions needs: (link: http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-0856-AVR-Instruction-Set-Manual.pdf)

[image: clock timings]

So for an `ADD Rd, Rr` instruction, an `AVR` CPU needs 1 clock cycle.

Take a desktop Intel CPU for example. It's common these days that they have a clock frequency of 2 GHz or more, which is 2 Billion cycles per second compared to the 16 million cycles per second on the Arduino's AVR CPU. So the Intel CPU beats the Arduino by far. Then again, the Arduino is designed for completley different stuff - it's a small microcontroller with low overhead, runs no OS etc. The use-case for such a CPU (and the architecture) is just different, which makes comparing them unjustified. There many other factors in play, like multi-core CPUs (4 Intel CPU cores vs. 1 AVR) and command pipelining, the speed of your memory / RAM, etc. It's really hard to compare a CPU to another one in every use-case possible, but for "general purpose computing", the Desktop CPUs (AMD, Intel, x64 architecture) far outruns the processing power of a mere Arduino AVR CPU.

I hope this clears up some confusion.

Comment: How does clock frequency relate to output pin's PWM frequency then?

Comment: @OneZero The clock frequency relates to the PWM frequency in a way that it can be no faster than the clockspeed divided by a configurable prescaler value. The hardware PWM is based on a hardware timer, which has a resolution in bits. The PWM frequency is basically `f_PWM = f_CPU / (2*prescaler)`, whereas `prescaler` on the AVR can be chosen from `1, 8, 64, 256, 1024`. Read https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SecretsOfArduinoPWM and http://www.cs.mun.ca/~rod/Winter2007/4723/notes/timer0/timer0.html for more info.

Comment: Does it mean that PWM cannot output arbitrary frequency, but only at certain levels? Then for example, if I want to make a pitch sound, the pitch might be at arbitrary frequency. How does that work?

Comment: If your PWM block is fed by say a 4Mhz clock, say your 16Mhz cpu clock is divided down by 4 for the peripherals.  then you simply do the math say you wanted a 100Khz square wave, that means 10us per period, but your reference clock for that logic is 250ns (4mhz) so you need to count to 40 ticks of the 4Mhz clock for every period of the PWM output clock if it is a 50 percent duty cycle that is 20 clocks high and 20 clocks low if you want 25 percent duty cycle then 10 clocks high 30 low, etc.  note 4Mhz/100K is 40...

Comment: dont remember off hand for the popular avrs used on arduinos but a lot of times you have a number of knobs you can control, divisors into the timer/pwm block, as well as the settings in the timer/pwm block to determine how many ref clocks to count for each state change of the output.

Answer (score 2):

I think one confusion you have may be chip specific, I am not going to look it up right now but I do remember seeing this, the chip spec may say that for this input voltage range it can handle this frequency and for this voltage range it cannot.  I think sparkfun the 3.3 are 8mhz and 5.0 are 16mhz or something like that.  Anyway, that is not generally the case, but it is a chip by chip vendor by vendor thing and that is why you have to read the datasheet.  Has nothing to do with arduinos or avrs specifically, just a general chip design thing.

How do you know how fast your microcontroller can run?  That is a very loaded question, depends on your definition of fast.  If it is simply what clock frequencies can I use, well "just read the datasheet" for that part, and then depending on your board design choose from what is available, if you do not have any external clocks then your choices may or may not be more limited, you may or may not have a pll that you can use to multiply the clock source.

if your definition of fast is how fast can I perform this task, how many whatevers per second or how much wall clock time does it take to complete some specific task.  Well that is a benchmark problem and there are so many variables that there is actually no real answer.  Yes it is very true that an x86 can have a lower clock and run faster than some other x86, historically the newer ones can do less stuff per clock than older ones for the same binaries, you have to then tune the compile to the newer chip and then you might get back some of your mips to mhz.  but that is in part because you are using a different chip design that just speaks the same language (machine code).  You can have a tall person that can recite a poem faster than a short person, both using english and the same poem, has nothing to do with them being short or tall, just that they are different humans.

There are different avr core variations but not remotely on par with the different x86 architectures.  so while comparing a tiny vs an xmega you can probably have the xmega run "faster" at the same clock rate simply because it has more registers or a bigger address space, etc.  But instructions per second is probably not really different, could be, but my guess is not so much.

Then there is the compiler, the compiler plays a huge role in how "fast" your code runs, change compilers or compiler versions or compiler settings and the machine code produced from the same high level source code (C for example) can vary greatly and as a result can have dramatic effects on the "speed" of the code.  Take the dhrystone for example, very easy to demonstrate that the same exact source code on the same exact chip/board, same clock rates, etc can execute at vastly different speeds based on either using different compilers, versions or command line settings, kinda proving that the godfather of benchmarks is basically useless in providing any meaningful information.

Microcontrollers make the problem much worse as you often are running the program out of flash, and many, not all, but many have the ability to either divide or multiply or both the clock, but the flash is not always designed for the full range.  You might have a chip that boots on an internal clock at 8mhz but you can use the pll to multiply that up to say 80mhz.  But not uncommon that the flash is limited to say 16mhz on a chip like that so at 8mhz the flash can deliver an item say an instruction every cpu clock, but at 20mhz you have to put a wait state and although the cpu is running much faster you can only feed it at 16mhz so it is waiting around more, and then acts fast when it gets something, is it really "faster" or is clocking up making you slower.  Certainly at just under 16mhz in this fantasy chip I am describing you can keep it to zero wait states so it is really faster, not necessarily twice as as there are other factors, but definitely faster than 8mhz.  just at or above 16mhz though you take a huge performance hit compared to just under 16mhz.  at just under 32mhz though it is pretty fast compared to just under, then at just over 32mhz another wait state setting and much slower again even though the clock is basically the same and so on.

Then there is the fetching, how does the cpu actually fetch, like an arm where it fetches a bunch of data per fetch transaction, even if it is not going to execute all of them if you branch to 0x1004 and at that address there is a branch to 0x2008 the core might fetch 0x10 bytes from 0x1000 to 0x100F, THEN extract the 0x1004 word/instruction, decode it to find it is a branch then read 0x10 bytes from 0x2000.  basically reading 0x20 bytes to find 2 instructions.  Take two instructions if both are in the 0x10 bytes then good if one is at 0x100C and the other at 0x2000 that is a performance hit.  take this internal information and apply it to an application and all of its jumping around, changing one line of code or adding or removing a single nop to the bootstrap (causing the alignment of the program to change in the address space) can cause anywhere from a tiny to a large change in performance, swap two helper function sin the source code of your program, in the text, causing them to land in different address spaces once compiled, can have little to major performance effects without actually changing the functions themselves.

So performance is first of a foolish task to go after in one respect, in the other respect all that matters is your program as written with the compiler you are using on the hardware you are using, it is as fast as it is, and there are things you can do to make that code faster on that compiler on that target on that day, by changing compiler settings or the code or both.  And ideally you build your final firmware, performance test that, and never build again as if you build a year or two later it may be on a different host compiler with a different compiler or compiler version and all bets are off on performance.

How do you pick a board, how much flash, ram, features, clock rate.  A lot of it is experience by just trial and error, you fortunately live in a time where you can literally try hundreds of boards all of which cost anywhere from a few bucks to like 10 or 20 each, different cpu architectures different chip vendors, etc.  there are many compiler choices and even languages available, basically there are too many easy to acquire choices, unlike back in the day when the parts were pretty cheap but you may have had to build your own board, write your code in asm, maybe even create your own assembler, etc.  Have a rom programmer that cost hundreds to thousands of dollars.  So go with the AVR you have and play with its features, play with the compiler and/or write or both.  Do experiments to see if there are fetch effects or not.  If you have clocking choices mess with those see what happens.

Of course all of this starts with reading the chip documentation from the vendor.

Comment: from your title question.  The frequency is ideally how fast the "clock" is, 16Mhz means every 62.5 nano seconds the logic is re-evaluated and changes state.  If you are playing the piano and you can change the notes once a second then you are at one hz, the prior note or chord determines the next chord in the song, but you can only go one hz lets say.  You can perhaps change the rule and allow 2hz, but maybe no tor maybe you cant play that fast.  same for logic it can only go so fast and then you have to put a clock out there at or less than that.